# vb.net rowfilter a datetime of 15 minutes ago

Tags: vb.net, datetime, rowfilter

I hope someone can help, I've been struggling with this for a few days now.

I am trying to filter out some records using a rowfilter that has a datetime in one of the columns that is older than 15 minutes ago, looking at it, this looks to me as though it would do it:

```
    Dim TimeStr As String
    TimeStr = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "#{0}#", Now.AddMinutes(-15))
    AlertsView.RowFilter = "StatusId < 3 AND LastEmailed < " & TimeStr
```

Before the filter there are 6 rows in the view but after the filter there are none, i know the StatusId field is correct as if i filter on just that it works fine.  All 6 rows have a LastEmailed value of 2013-09-03 23:06:44.813

I'm thinking it might be something with the string conversion but i am stuck.

Many thanks

Comment: If you put a break point on the line `AlertsView.RowFilter = "StatusId < 3 AND LastEmailed < " & TimeStr`, then what is the value of `TimeStr`?

Comment: Not sure, so I post as comment, but CultureInfo.InvarianCulture produces #09/05/2013 xx:xx:xx# not the expected format that you have said

Comment: #09/05/2013 17:15:48# is the value of TimeStr

Comment: @Steve the value i put above is what i pulled straight from the database.

would it just be a case of changing the date format?

Comment: Just to test if there is a difference, try with `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`

Comment: With CultureInfo.CurrentCulture gives #05/09/2013 17:23:34#

Comment: Of what data type is the `LastEmailed` field??? Is it for sure a DateTime?? - If not, you might not be able to use the `<` operator on it... Just a thought....

Comment: Yep definitely DateTime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything between the two `#` characters in a `RowFilter` expression will be ultimately passed into `DateTime.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`.

This should be mentioned in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) for `DataColumn.Expression`, but it isn't.  However, if you dig really deep you can find it in the constructor of the internal class [System.Data.ConstNode](http://typedescriptor.net/browse/members/394733-System.Data.ConstNode..ctor%28DataTable,ValueType,Object,Boolean%29).

So as long as you are generating values that are unambiguous in the invariant culture, you should be fine.  Just to be on the safe side, you might want to use the [`"s"` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Sortable) to give you a value like `2013-12-31T12:34:56`.  Change your format string to `"#{0:s}#"`.

Or much cleaner:

```
Dim TimeStr As String
TimeStr = Now.AddMinutes(-15).ToString("s", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
AlertsView.RowFilter = "StatusId < 3 AND LastEmailed < #" & TimeStr & "#"
```

`String.Format` doesn't buy you much here.

Also - just out of curiosity, are you sure you are not comparing apples to oranges?  It wouldn't be uncommon for a database to store UTC time in a field like `LastEmailed`.  You might need to use `DateTime.UtcNow` instead of just `Now` (which is an alias for `DateTime.Now`).

Comment: Matt, thank you for pointing that out, it now works as expected.